# sometimes my mail server doesn't send the emails

Tags: email, amazon-s3, webmail, mail-server

I'm usign amazon cloud services to host my webpage. Our web site, actually sends a lot of emails per hour. In one instant our server could be asked to send 30 mails or more.

Sometimes our clients complaint about not getting emails from the web, which is connected to our mail server to send emails. This doesn't happen if we send the email directly from our addresses to theirs, so I'm pretty much know is the web page who's causing the problem.

The thing is I don't know what is happening and neither know what to look for. I've checked memory and cpu of that server and everything seems to work fine

Comment: Have you checked your _server logs_?

Comment: Did you try to send the _identical_ content in your hand-tests? Quite often anti-spam systems will just drop HTML email or use heuristics to guess if emails are spam. Perhaps your mails look funny. Is your MTA address in an [RBL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL)?

Comment: but if they look funny they wouldn't get at all... That's not happening, sometimes they arrive, sometimes they don't

Comment: Is there a coding question here?

Answer (score 0):

- make sure your website sends the messages with a correct **bounce address** (aka envelope sender address). this does not have to be the same thing as the address in the *From*: header. by default, this is often something like "apache@www.example.com" - I don't know about amazon). these types of bounce addresses are bad because usually you don't receive the error message if something goes wrong. use a real email account. To check what bounce address you currently use, look at the message source of a received mail and see the *Return-Path* header.
- check the **logs** of your mailserver for those missing messages. either it reports an error (in which case you should get the error to your bounce address) or it reports the message as sent to the target server (in which case you tell your clients to check THEIR maillogs since you can prove you have sent the message)